# PHP code that will display all links that are visited more than 20 times

Tags: php, mysql, xcode, ranking

I am looking for help in my project. I want to display all those links which are visited more then 20 times and also highest visited site will be at first.

I mean if google is visited through my website for 50 times then it will come to rank 1 like

1) [a link]Google[a]

Now second is Facebook which is visited for 30 times then it will come to

2) [a link]Facebook[a]

and if Facebook is viewed for 60 times then it will automatically come to first rank and Google will be at second.

For the rank, I've created column in database and it will always increase by +1 after every redirection to the website.

Please help me with PHP and MySQL code.

My table structure is:

```
ID, URL, CODE, DATE, VIEW, KEYWORD, DESCRIPTION
```

these are my codes :-

```
$a = "SELECT `url` FROM `url` ORDER BY `view` DESC";

$b = mysql_query($a);

$c = mysql_fetch_array($b);

print_r ($c);
```

and the result I am getting is

```
Array ( [0] => https://www.google.com [url] => https://www.google.com )
```

where I want

```
[0] =>google.com
[1] =>facebook.com
[1] =>linkedin.com
```

so any suggestions?

Comment: add your table structure, so we can help you to build the code

Comment: *"so we can help to **"build"** the code"* ?? @SumitBijvani – It's the OP's job, not ours.

Comment: `so please help me with php and mysql codes..` -- I'm sorry, but pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yah it is, but he want help from us.

Comment: if you can't build the code then at least you can suggest me something @Fred-ii-

Comment: @SumitBijvani Help and building are 2 different animals altogether ;-)

Comment: @user2947999 What you need is to hire a developer. This is quite the request.

Comment: @user2947999 i have added query, now you can use php code and display the records accordingly.

Comment: @Sumit, Fred is right. The view here is strongly in favour of matching an OP's effort with their own; if the OP effectively asks for free coding, the question should be placed on hold until they show what they have tried themselves. I would have thought your rep is high enough for you to have encountered this perspective before `:)`.

Comment: @user2947999, how many rows do you have in your table? You want three results but there's only one in there, from what you've shown.

Comment: right now in localhost there are 4 rows, and only fist row got 43 views. I want to show only those rows which's views are more then 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple, SELECT views in `DESC` order, (Highest to Lowest)

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY `VIEW` DESC
```

**EDIT**

```
$a = "SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY `view` DESC";
$b = mysql_query($a);
while($c = mysql_fetch_array($b))
{
    echo "<a href='$c[url]'>$c[url]</a> ". $c['view'] . " Views";
}
```